# create a vm from host os using vmware -aka clone host os to vm guest image

Tags: vmware

This question must be a repeat since it sounds obvious but I cannot seem to find a solution online. I have win 7 x64 running vmware workstation. I need to create a guest vm which is a clone of my host os. (win 7 x64). Can this be done ? If yes please post the link or getting started solution or steps. Do not confuse with the clone feature in vm. That merely clones an existing guest vm so you can take it to another machine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) does what you want. I tested that sometime ago and it worked pretty good. But I think you need a second Windows license for that.